# Negative value for factor in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a factor variable, but with negative values behind the labels.  Is this not allowed?

```
> foo <- sample( -10:-1, 20, replace=T)
> factor( foo, levels=-1:-10 )
 [1] -7  -10 -8  -9  -2  -2  -1  -5  -7  -6  -6  -9  -1  -1  -6 
[16] -2  -9  -1  -4  -1 
Levels: -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -10
> 
> foo2 <- factor( foo, levels=-1:-10, labels=letters[16:25] )
> foo2
 [1] v y w x q q p t v u u x p p u q x p s p
Levels: p q r s t u v w x y
```

Values are positive! why?

```
> as.numeric( foo2 )
 [1]  7 10  8  9  2  2  1  5  7  6  6  9  1  1  6  2  9  1  4  1
```

*[why would I want this? I was creating a heatmap with `geom_tile()` and wanted the column labels at the top of chart instead of bottom ... the solution to move this seems surprisingly complicated:
[ggplot2: Adding secondary transformed x-axis on top of plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026598/ggplot2-adding-secondary-transformed-x-axis-on-top-of-plot/21028809#21028809)
and I thought I might fool ggplot by giving negative values to put the chart in the IV quadrant but alas...*]

Comment: No, factors use positive integer codes by design.

Comment: I think you would be overloading the meaning of a levels of a factor if you did that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set negative labels, but perhaps not levels:

```
j = factor("Jack", levels=c("Jack", "Jill", "tumbling", "after"), labels=c(-1,0,1,2))
print(j)
## [1] -1
## Levels: -1 0 1 2
levels(j)
## [1] "-1" "0"  "1"  "2" 
as.integer(levels(j)[as.integer(j)])
## [1] -1
```

However, you won't get your expected value when using `as.integer()` or `as.numeric()` in the normal manner:

```
as.numeric(j)
## [1] 1
as.integer(j)
## [1] 1
```