# Combining Bar and Line chart (double axis) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, linechart, yaxis

I have `double-y-axis` chart made in `Excel`. In Excel it requires only basic skills. What I'd like to do is to replicate this chart using the `ggplot2` library in `R`.

[image]

I have already done this, but I need to plot Response on `2nd-y-axis`.

[image]

I enclose reproducible code I've used:

```
#Data generation
Year <- c(2014, 2015, 2016)
Response <- c(1000, 1100, 1200)
Rate <- c(0.75, 0.42, 0.80)

df <- data.frame(Year, Response, Rate)

#Chart
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Response),stat="identity", fill="tan1", colour="sienna3")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Rate),stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Rate, x=Year, y=Rate), colour="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Response, x=Year, y=0.9*Response), colour="black")
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First, scale `Rate` by `Rate*max(df$Response)` and modify the `0.9` scale of Response text.

Second, include a second axis via `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=...)`:

```
ggplot(df)  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Response),stat="identity", fill="tan1", colour="sienna3")+
    geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Rate*max(df$Response)),stat="identity")+
    geom_text(aes(label=Rate, x=Year, y=Rate*max(df$Response)), colour="black")+
    geom_text(aes(label=Response, x=Year, y=0.95*Response), colour="black")+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(df$Response)))
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: Hello, how can I change the limits of the secondary y axis? I am trying to create a similar graph with percentage (already multiplied by 100) and the scale on the secondary graph is not appropriate. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem as @user3047435. A lot of things I tried messed up the scaling, so for e.g. the Rate would be right but the Response was thrown out. Ultimately, I ended up taking the original percentage back down to being divided by 100, but then multiplied it again in the scaling, like so: `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(df$Response)*100))`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the syntax **label=scales::percent** to make the secondary axis into percentage :
[Click Here for Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2uXO.jpg)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Response),stat="identity", fill="tan1", 
  colour="sienna3")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=Rate*max(df$Response)),stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Rate, x=Year, y=Rate*max(df$Response)), colour="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Response, x=Year, y=0.95*Response), colour="black")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(df$Response),label=scales::percent))
```