# R studio ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**my code:**

```
ggplot(data)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=data$AgeGroup, y=data$NumberofLoans), stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(x=data$AgeGroup, y=data$BadRate*max(data$NumberofLoans)) , stat="identity",group=1)+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(data$NumberofLoans)))
```

can anyone help me out to get the second graph as the answer. Currently i am getting the first graph

**Data:**

```
AgeGroup,NumberofLoans,BadLoans,GoodLoans,BadRate
21-24,310,14,296,4.5
24-27,511,20,491,3.9
27-30,4000,172,3828,4.3
30-33,4568,169,4399,3.7
33-36,5698,188,5510,3.3
36-39,8209,197,8012,2.4
39-42,8117,211,7906,2.6
42-45,9000,216,8784,2.4
45-48,7600,152,7448,2
48-51,6000,84,5916,1.4
51-54,4000,64,3936,1.6
54-57,2000,26,1974,1.3
57-60,788,9,779,1.1
```

[image: my graph]

[image: required graph]

Comment: Did you have a question to ask? I see a code and pictures...

Comment: Don't use `data$column` inside `aes()`. Just use column names.

Comment: Thats done , the problem is i want the graphs to get overlapped

Comment: Second y-axis starts from 0 and in second plot it starts from 1

Comment: How do i start y axis from 1

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345930/change-limits-of-secondary-y-axis-ggplot-r

Answer (score -1):

Try:

---

```
ggplot(data)+
geom_bar(aes(x=data$AgeGroup, y=data$NumberofLoans), stat="identity")+
geom_line(aes(x=data$AgeGroup, y=data$BadRate*max(data$NumberofLoans)) , 
stat="identity",group=1)+
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(data$NumberofLoans)), limits = c(0,8500))
```

---

limits() is a parameter that allows you to specify the limits of the initial axis

Comment: for the secondary axis too?

Comment: @PoGibas you can use breaks for the secondary axis I believe, but I think the problem here is in the main axis's scale