# How to create both Bar & Line Charts in R (ggplot2) at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

This is the code and dataframe I used for my analysis for creating bar & line chart.

I am trying to create a graph where it shows visit_frequency (bar chart) on Primary Y axis and visit_duration_avg (line chart) on Secondary Y axis and it should show visit_sequence_number on X axis

```
library(ggplot2)

df<- data.frame(visit_sequence_number=c(1:5),
                visit_frequency=c(697754,416613,263433,178823,128599),
                visit_duration_avg=c(133,121,121,122,124))


ggplot(df)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=visit_sequence_number, y=visit_frequency),stat="identity",fill="tan1", colour="sienna3")+
  geom_line(aes(x=visit_sequence_number, y=visit_duration_avg*max(df$visit_frequency)),stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=visit_duration_avg, x=visit_sequence_number,
                y=visit_duration_avg*max(df$visit_frequency)), colour="black")+
  geom_text(aes(label=visit_frequency, x=visit_sequence_number, y=0.95*visit_frequency), colour="black")+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./max(df$visit_frequency)))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to create a graph where it shows visit_frequency (bar chart) on Primary Y axis and visit_duration_avg (line chart) on Secondary Y axis and it should show visit_sequence_number on X axis .

Comment: Why do you multiply your duration averages by the maximum visit frequency, and not by the corresponding visit frequency per row?

Comment: @LAP :How do I do that ? multiplying corresponding  visit frequency per row ?

Comment: Just use `visit_duration_avg*visit_frequency` instead of `visit_duration_avg*max(df$visit_frequency)`

Comment: It does not work , and i get error like                                                  
Error in geom_text(aes(label = visit_frequnecy, x = visit_sequence_number,  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It works for me, maybe it's a typo? `(label = visit_frequnecy,` in your error above.

Comment: It did not work for me .....it is not a typo....I simply used code from the below solution and this did not work for me ....                                                                                               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764312/combining-bar-and-line-chart-double-axis-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with ggplot2. Please see the following answer from the creator of the package (Hadley Wickham):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/8357864