# dual y-axis (bar and line) in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data I have contain four columns: `x`, `y_cnt`, `y1_rate`, `y2_rate`.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- seq(1,10)
y_cnt <- rnorm(10, 200, 50)
y1_rate <- runif(10,0,1)
y2_rate <- runif(10,0,1)
df <- data.frame(x, y_cnt, y1_rate, y2_rate)
```

I need to produce a plot such that `x` is on the x-axis, both `y1_rate` and `y2_rate` are on the main y-axis, and `y_cnt` on the secondary y-axis.

Here how it looks in Excel:

[image]

**Update:**

This is what I've so far. It seems that the figure below shows `y1_rate` only.

```
transf_fact <- max(df$y_cnt)/max(df$y1_rate)

# Plot
ggplot(data = df,
       mapping = aes(x = as.factor(x),
                     y = y_cnt)) +
  geom_col(fill = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y = transf_fact * y1_rate), group = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = transf_fact * y2_rate)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact, 
                                         name = "Rate"))+
  labs(x = "X")
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps may be helpful to consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53922846/plot-line-and-bar-graph-with-secondary-axis-for-line-graph-using-ggplot

Comment: Could you add what you tried already?

Comment: @Sven, please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that adjusts the scaling of the `rate` variables, then gathers all the series into long form, and then shows the variables with their respective geoms.

```
transf_fact <- max(df$y_cnt)/max(df$y1_rate)

library(tidyverse) # Using v1.2.1

df %>%
  # Scale any variables with "rate" in their name
  mutate_at(vars(matches("rate")), ~.*transf_fact) %>%
  # Gather into long form; 
  #  one column specifying variable, one column specifying value
  gather(y_var, val, -x) %>%

  # Pipe into ggplot; all layers share x, y, and fill/color columns
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(x), y = val, fill = y_var)) +
  # bar chart only uses "y_cnt" data
  geom_col(data = . %>% filter(y_var == "y_cnt")) +
  # lines only use non-"y_cnt" data
  geom_line(data = . %>% filter(y_var != "y_cnt"),
            aes(color = y_var, group = y_var),
            size = 1.2) +
  # Use the "fill" aesthetic to control both colour and fill;
  # geom_col typically uses fill, geom_line uses colour
  scale_fill_discrete(aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . / transf_fact, 
                                         name = "Rate")) +
  labs(x = "X")
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried to run your code and got the following error: ``` Error in UseMethod("as.fun_list") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.fun_list' applied to an object of class "formula"```. Do you know what went wrong?

Comment: Are you running with the example data or something new? I reloaded R, loaded your example data, and ran my code no problems. I would suggest removing pipes (the `%>%`) and seeing which step is making that error, as it's not obvious to me.