# ggplot bar plot by multiple groups + line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, linegraph

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(team = c("bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", 
"bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", 
"bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", 
"bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", 
"bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", "bgr", 
"chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", 
"chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chj", 
"chj", "chj", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", 
"chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", 
"chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "chn", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", 
"lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", 
"lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "lev", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", 
"mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", 
"mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbn", 
"mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", 
"mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", 
"mbn", "mbn", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", 
"mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", 
"mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "mrb", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", 
"rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", 
"rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl"), tmp = c("P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", 
"P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", 
"P3", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3"), day_s = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Mo", "Di", "Mi", 
"Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), mpd = c(108, 
93, 92, 60, 98, 96, 30, 57, 58, 60, 47, 78, 65, 87, 67, 72, 76, 
27, 54, 63, 42, 96, 62, 73, 27, 17, 33, 45, 51, 69, 29, 29, 59, 
38, 17, 120, 59, 30, 30, 68, 30, 18, 68, 32, 71, 73, 81, 28, 
38, 90, 107, 60, 43, 38, 22, 5, 150, 120, 90, 120, 90, 113, 91, 
89, 69, 80, 114, 30, 56, 169, 186, 69, 95, 132, 75, 104, 60, 
189, 250, 139, 180, 58, 180, 117, 107, 50, 127, 162, 11, 130, 
58, 88, 82, 98, 75, 110, 158, 80, 18, 120, 120, 70, 89, 106, 
85, 103, 130, 50, 65, 84, 120, 84, 38, 100, 108, 30, 90, 50, 
63, 120, 80, 70, 90, 71, 28, 77, 98, 70, 60, 64, 62, 63, 71, 
34, 27, 51, 38, 104, 130, 90, 150, 105, 132, 66, 99, 23, 79, 
77, 51, 26, 71, 80, 78, 102, 38, 66, 42, 52, 119, 44, 41, 133, 
278, 51, 78, 55, 89, 71, 93, 56, 61, 79, 60, 150, 79, 52, 85, 
52, 118, 98, 62, 58, 60, 68, 87), rpd = c(6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
9, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 7, 
9, 8, 9, 6, 8, 4, 3, 6, 6, 5, 2, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
6, 6, 6, 5, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 6, 9, 6, 7, 4, 8, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 8, 8, 6, 7, 6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 
7, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 6, 8, 5, 4, 6, 7, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 8, 7, 6, 
7, 5, 7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5, 8, 11, 8, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 6, 10, 10, 7, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -185L
), groups = structure(list(team = c("bgb", "bgb", "bgb", "bgr", 
"bgr", "bgr", "chj", "chj", "chj", "chn", "chn", "chn", "lev", 
"lev", "lev", "mbj", "mbj", "mbj", "mbn", "mbn", "mbn", "mrb", 
"mrb", "mrb", "rwl", "rwl", "rwl"), tmp = c("P1", "P2", "P3", 
"P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P2", 
"P3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P1", 
"P2", "P3"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28, 
    29:35, 36:42, 43:49, 50:56, 57:62, 63:69, 70:76, 77:83, 84:90, 
    91:97, 98:101, 102:108, 109:115, 116:122, 123:129, 130:136, 
    137:143, 144:150, 151:157, 158:164, 165:171, 172:178, 179:185), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -27L), .drop = TRUE), na.action = structure(c(`8` = 8L, 
`16` = 16L, `24` = 24L, `32` = 32L, `40` = 40L, `48` = 48L, `56` = 56L, 
`64` = 64L, `65` = 65L, `72` = 72L, `80` = 80L, `88` = 88L, `96` = 96L, 
`104` = 104L, `112` = 112L, `113` = 113L, `118` = 118L, `126` = 126L, 
`134` = 134L, `142` = 142L, `150` = 150L, `158` = 158L, `166` = 166L, 
`174` = 174L, `182` = 182L, `190` = 190L, `198` = 198L, `206` = 206L, 
`214` = 214L), class = "omit"), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want to illustrate the variable mpd as bars, but differntiated by "day_s" (Monday to Sunday) and tmp (phases 1 to 3).
This is the plot I get if its just differentiatet the variable day_s:

```
ggplot(tab_tra)  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd), stat="identity")
```

[image]

But I want that after Sunday it starts with Monday again (the Monday of P2) and after that the third week. The x-axis basically consists of three weeks (P1, P2 and P3). The bars of each week should have different colors. For example the bars of the first week are blue, the second green and the third red.
Additionally, I want to add a line which illustrates the course of the variable "rpd" over those three weeks with a seperate y-axis.

I have not find the right approach to build this plot. So I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any kinds of help.

Cheers

Update:

I used the approach @JKupzig suggested. It works so far, but I have trouble adding the linegraph (see below):

```
ggplot(tab_tra, aes(fill = tmp))  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd), stat="identity") +
    geom_line(aes(x=day_s, y=rpd*10))+
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.*10, name= "rpd Axis"))+
    facet_grid(~ tmp)+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: When you use +geom_point(aes(x=day_s, y=rpd*10, group=tmp),stat="identity") you can notice that you have several values for rpd (due to the different 'teams'). In the barplot, the values of the teams are summed up - do you wish to do the same for the rpd-values in the line plot?

Comment: Yes, I want the rpd-values summed up, too.

Comment: See my update of my answer @psycho95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use facet_wrap to plot the weeks beside each other:

```
 ggplot(data, aes(fill=tmp))  + 
   geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd, group=tmp) ,stat="identity") +
   facet_wrap(.~tmp) +
   theme_bw()
```

**Update**
To get summed up rpd as line plot you can do the following:

```
    library(dplyr)

rpd_sum <- data %>% 
  group_by(tmp, day_s) %>%
  summarise(sum_rpd = sum(rpd)) %>%
  mutate(newClass = paste(tmp, day_s))

data$newClass <- paste(data$tmp, data$day_s)
dataNew <- merge(data, rpd_sum )  


ggplot(dataNew, aes(fill=tmp))  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd) ,stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x=day_s, y=sum_rpd*10, group=tmp),stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( trans=~./10, name="rpd Axis")) +
  facet_wrap(.~tmp) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JKupzig, that is what I was looking for. But do you also know how to add a linegraph in this plot?

Comment: ``` + geom_line()```

Comment: See here an example how to solve that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764312/combining-bar-and-line-chart-double-axis-in-ggplot2

Comment: I added `geom_line(aes(x=day_s, y=rpd), stat = "identity")` to the code but nothing happens

Comment: because rpd has a different scale than mpd you have to transform rpd e.g. geom_line(...aes(...y=rpd*10)... and add a second y-axis e.g. scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( trans=~.*10, name="rpd Axis"))

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add the linegraph but it's not the right way (see update in question)

Comment: `Warning message:
Removed 1986 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).`  It doesn't work, this is the warning I receive

Comment: I applied the code to the structure you provided and I do not get any warning. I added the plot I obtain with my code. Please make sure that you use the updated code corretcly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding a facet is likely the simplest solution.

```
ggplot(tab_tra)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd), stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(~ tmp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `tmp` as a factor

```
tab_tra$tmp<- as.factor(tab_tra$tmp)
```

then

```
ggplot(tab_tra)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd, fill = tmp), stat="identity" )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customise with `dodge()`

```
 ggplot(df, aes(fill=tmp))  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd, group=tmp),stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
          theme_bw()
```

[image]

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=tmp))  + 
geom_bar(aes(x=day_s, y=mpd, group=tmp),stat="identity", position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5, preserve = "single", padding = -0.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]