# Combining bar and line plot, different y axis, without ggplot

Tags: r

I would like to create a similar graph like that but without ggplot2: [Combining Bar and Line chart (double axis) in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764312/combining-bar-and-line-chart-double-axis-in-ggplot2)

Looking for an answer that allows more simple visual than ggplot. The main issue with ggplot is adjusting the secondary axis plus the not so simple graphs. For an academic publicatoin a strpped-down graph is preferable.

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you share some sample data? And then what have you tried? Can you share some code to get us started?

Comment: *"Looking for an answer that allows more simple visual than ggplot"* this seems like a weird reason to go to base graphics - ggplot themes are very flexible. `theme_minimal()` or `ggthemes::theme_tufte()` are very stripped-down, and any theme can be further customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Gregor that `ggplot` with a minimal theme is likely the correct tool for this, I thought it was interesting enough give it a try with base R.  It was harder than I thought it would be:

```
 # Define some data, two sets of values to plot
 y1 = c(10,20,30)
 y2 = c(40,60,53)
 
 # Against one group variable
 group = c("A","B","C")
 
 # How much space to leave between the bars?
 space=0.2
 
 # Give some room for the second y-axis
 par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
 
 # Work out the x-limits of the graph
 xlim=c(0,space+(1+space)*length(group))
 
 # Work out the x-location of the bar centres/points
 x=(1+space)*seq_along(group)-0.5
 
 # Plot the bar graph
 barplot(y1, space=space, xlim=xlim,col="red", xlab="Group", ylab="y1")
 
 # Add the x=axis
 axis(1, labels=group, at=x)

 # Start a new graph without overwriting the old one
 par(new=TRUE)
 
 # Add the line graph
 plot(x, y2, axes=F, type="b", xlim, ann=F,pch=20)
 
 # Add the second y axis
 axis(4)
 
 # Add the second y label
 mtext("y2", side=4, line=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a fairly similar chart using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data.frame(Group, y1, y2), aes(Group)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = y1), fill = "red", color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = (y2-40)*1.5, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = (y2-40)*1.5, group = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~(.x/1.5+40), name = "y2")) +
  ggthemes::theme_par()
```

[image]