# R/ggplot Cumulative Sum in Histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with user IDs and the number of objects they created. I drew the histogram using ggplot and now I'm trying to include the cumulative sum of the x-values as a line. The aim is to see much the bins contribute to the total number. I tried the following:

```
ggplot(data=userStats,aes(x=Num_Tours)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)+
   scale_x_log10(name = 'Number of planned tours',breaks=c(1,5,10,50,100,200))+
   geom_line(aes(x=Num_Tours, y=cumsum(Num_Tours)/sum(Num_Tours)*3500),color="red")+
   scale_y_continuous(name = 'Number of users', sec.axis = sec_axis(~./3500, name = "Cummulative percentage of routes [%]"))
```

This does not work because I don't include any bins so the plot

and

```
ggplot(data=userStats,aes(x=Num_Tours)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2)+
   scale_x_log10(name = 'Number of planned tours',breaks=c(1,5,10,50,100,200))+
   stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)),binwidth = 0.2, geom="line",color="red")+
   scale_y_continuous(name = 'Number of users', sec.axis = sec_axis(~./3500, name = "Cummulative percentage of routes [%]"))
```

Resulting in this: 
[image: Result 1].

Here the cumsum of the count is considered. What I want is the cumsum of the count * value of the bin. Then it should be normalized, so that it can be displayed in one plot. What I am trying to to is something like that:

[image: Example]

I would appreciate any input! Thanks

**Edit:**
As test data, this should work:

```
userID <- c(1:100)
Num_Tours <- sample(1:100,100)
userStats <- data.frame(userID,Num_Tours)
userStats$cumulative <- cumsum(userStats$Num_Tours/sum(userStats$Num_Tours))
```

Comment: example data please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an illustrative example that could be helpful for you.

```
set.seed(111)
userID <- c(1:100)
Num_Tours <- sample(1:100, 100, replace=T)
userStats <- data.frame(userID, Num_Tours)

# Sorting x data
userStats$Num_Tours <- sort(userStats$Num_Tours)
userStats$cumulative <- cumsum(userStats$Num_Tours/sum(userStats$Num_Tours))

library(ggplot2)
# Fix manually the maximum value of y-axis
ymax <- 40
ggplot(data=userStats,aes(x=Num_Tours)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2, col="white")+
   scale_x_log10(name = 'Number of planned tours',breaks=c(1,5,10,50,100,200))+
   geom_line(aes(x=Num_Tours,y=cumulative*ymax), col="red", lwd=1)+
   scale_y_continuous(name = 'Number of users', sec.axis = sec_axis(~./ymax, 
    name = "Cumulative percentage of routes [%]"))
```

[image]