# add two linear regression lines and two y axis in ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a plot with two y-axes and add two linear regression lines to each group. I have seen some methods on this website, and it is easy for me to get two y-axes for the points. But I can not control the linear regression lines.
The plot I want to make like this:

[image]

My data are as following:

```
   ggplot(plotdata) + geom_point(aes(x,z),colour="green") + 
   geom_smooth(aes(x,y), method=lm, se=FALSE,colour="green") + 
   geom_point(aes(x,y*100), colour="red") + 
   geom_smooth(aes(x,y*100), method=lm, se=FALSE,colour="red") +  
   scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.01))
```

I used the upper code to make this plot, but I always got the following result:

[image]

It seems like the sec.axis method cannot control the second regression line.

Could anyone give me some reminders?
Tons of thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two variables as lines using ggplot2 on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777174/plotting-two-variables-as-lines-using-ggplot2-on-the-same-graph)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. 
I have seen this question.
I can control the point with two y axes.
But I can not control the linear regression lines.

Comment: The two y-axes solution is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Comment: Don’t use ggplot2 functions. Use ‘predict’.

Comment: Do you mean I didn't use ggplot2 to draw this plot? What is predict? Is it a package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple y axis for bar plot and line graph using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194147/multiple-y-axis-for-bar-plot-and-line-graph-using-ggplot)

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be duplicated. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194147/multiple-y-axis-for-bar-plot-and-line-graph-using-ggplot)

```
library(ggplot2)
z=200*(y=1:10)
x=2.7*y

factor<-50

p1<-ggplot(plotdata) + geom_point(aes(x,y*factor), colour="red") +
  geom_smooth(aes(x,y*factor), method=lm, se=FALSE,colour="red") 

p1+geom_point(aes(x,z),colour="green") +  labs(y="z")+
  geom_smooth(aes(x,z), method=lm, se=FALSE,colour="green")+     scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 50))
```

[image]