# Adding two regression graphs having problem in dots and lines

Tags: r

I cannot find my answer anywhere.
I have two regression lines from two different datasets. I am trying to put these two regression lines in one graph. The following worked well.

```
regression1<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata1) 
regression2<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata2)
abline(regression1)
abline(regression2)
```

However in this plot I just have lines and I don't have dots. I run:

```
regression1<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata1)
regression2<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata2)
plot(c(0,2),c(0,2),type="n") +
points(rnorm(200), rnorm(200), col = "red") 
abline(regression1) 
abline(regression2)
```

With this command, I had just dots and I don't have lines, still does not work for me. What I want is having one graph with two different lines (representing the each regression's fitted lines) and dots of these regressions. I want these with different colours. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(mydata1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mydata1, 20))`. And the same with `mydata2`.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot share the data, could you give an example from datasets from the R?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577271/add-two-linear-regression-lines-and-two-y-axis-in-ggplots

Comment: With me the problem, with a fake dataset, was to open the graphics device with `plot(c(0,2), c(0,2), etc)`. The regression lines were *outside* the plotting area. I solved this problem with `with(mydata1, plot(range(X), range(Y), type = "n"))
`.

Comment: `reg1<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata1)
reg2<-lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata2)
with(mydata1, plot(range(X), range(Y), type = "n"))+
with(mydata2, plot(range(X, range(Y), type = "n")) +
abline(reg1)  
abline(reg2)` This does not work @RuiBarradas

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, using base R graphics, you plot something and it doesn't show up in the graph the odds are that you have plotted it outside the plot area. In the example below I will make sure that everything is in the plot area by first getting appropriate `x` and `y` axis limits.

The first two code lines do the trick.

```
rangeX <- range(c(mydata1$X, mydata2$X))
rangeY <- range(c(mydata1$Y, mydata2$Y))

regression1 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata1)
regression2 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata2)
plot(rangeX, rangeY, type = "n", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
with(mydata1, points(X, Y, col = "red"))
with(mydata2, points(X, Y, col = "blue"))
abline(regression1, col = "red")
abline(regression2, col = "blue")
```

[image]

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)

n <- 20
x <- seq_len(n) + rnorm(n)
mydata1 <- data.frame(X = x, Y = x + rnorm(n))
x <- seq_len(n) + rnorm(n)
mu <- 3
mydata2 <- data.frame(X = x + rnorm(n), Y = mu + x + rnorm(n))
```

Comment: I wanted to ad the median line to the graph but it does not show in the line with the following. What might be the problem @RuiBarradas  `rangeX <- range(c(mydata1$X, mydata2$X))
rangeY <- range(c(mydata1$Y, mydata2$Y))

regression1 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata1)
regression2 <- lm(Y ~ X, data = mydata2)
plot(rangeX, rangeY, type = "n", xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
with(mydata1, points(X, Y, col = "red"))
with(mydata2, points(X, Y, col = "blue"))
abline(h = median(mydata1$X), col="black", lwd=3, lty=2)
abline(regression1, col = "red")
abline(regression2, col = "blue")`