# Is there a nice way to plot two regression lines on one plot?

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I need to plot two regresion lines y(x) and x(y) on one plot. Is there any better way than doing this (and if not is it the right way to do it?):
1. counting regression parameters y~x
2. counting regression parameters x~y
3. transforming parameters from 2) 
4. plotting two lines with abline

ever graphical package is good for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add two linear regression lines and two y axis in ggplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51577271/add-two-linear-regression-lines-and-two-y-axis-in-ggplots)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of this post, user here want's to plot `x(y)` and `y(x)` lines whereas the user in the other question wants to plot `y(x)` and `z(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the builtin `BOD` as an example:

```
plot(demand ~ Time, BOD)
fm1 <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)
fm2 <- lm(Time ~ demand, BOD)
abline(fm1)
lines(demand ~ fitted(fm2), BOD, col = "red")
```

[image]