# R Overlay Line Plot on BarPlot with 2 axes

Tags: r

I have the following code and it is only producing a barplot without the line. How can I tweak this code to get the secondary line?
[image]

```html
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot()
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data=subset(df, Year==2006), aes(x=factor(State),y=Rate), stat = "identity")
p1 <- p1 + xlab("State") + ylab("Rate") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) 
p1 <- p1 +  geom_line(data = subset(df, Year==2006),  aes(x=factor(State),y=Total.Poverty/1000),colour = "blue") 
p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Total Poverty"))
print(p1)
```

I've looked at [ggplot2 overlay of barplot and line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094586/ggplot2-overlay-of-barplot-and-line-plot) and I still can't figure out why the plot isn't showing the line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a minimal data set to reproduce your problem, so I cannot test my solution, but I assume it is because a line on a factor scale does not work, so you should use:

```
p1 <- p1 +  geom_line(data = subset(df, Year == 2006),  
                      aes(x = State, y = Total.Poverty / 1000), colour = "blue")
```

instead.

Comment: I tried that and no success.

Let me show you what I have. Reattaching file in original thread.

df<-read.csv('Shiny/Vax.csv')

df[4:17] <- lapply(df[4:17], as.numeric)
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="variable"] <- "Year"
df <- df[,-1]

Answer (score 0):

Had to add group =  1 in the code

```html
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot()
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data=subset(df, Year==2006), aes(x=factor(State),y=Rate), stat = "identity")
p1 <- p1 + xlab("State") + ylab("Rate") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) 
p1 <- p1 +  geom_line(data = subset(df, Year==2006),  aes(x=factor(State),y=Total.Poverty/1000),colour = "blue", group = 1) 
p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1000, name = "Total Poverty"))
print(p1)
```