# Overlay bar and line plots using ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, overlay, ggpubr

I am trying to make an overlaid plot, having 2 y-axes. I want one plot to be a bar plot and the other to be a line plot. I know how to do this in `ggplot2` (i.e. [ggplot2 overlay of barplot and line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094586/ggplot2-overlay-of-barplot-and-line-plot)), but I would like to learn how to do this using the `ggpubr` package. I'd be grateful for any insight anyone can provide! **I know is is an elementary question, so thank you for bearing with me!**

In the interest of clarity, I have included the sample data frame provided by @SpencerTrinh in the linked question.

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(frax = c(16,30,60,64), solvb = c(0,0,100,100))
df2 <- data.frame(type = factor(c("mascot","mstat"), levels = c("mascot","mstat")), 
                 frax = c(30,35,40,45,50,55), phos = c(542,413,233,500,600,650))
```

This is what I'm looking for:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with ggpubr, but it's worth noting that the ggplot2 solution was written before ggplot supported a secondary axis with the [sec_axis argument](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html), and you may have some luck with that.

Comment: Hey @Dubukay! Yeah - I've been messing around with that but I think I'm missing something earlier, as I keep getting an error saying I can't "add to a ggplot object." I can make both the line plot and the bar plot on their own so I know the issue is in trying to combine them. I'm stumped