# Reproduce a 'The Economist' chart with dual axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I was trying to replicate this 
[chart](http://www.economist.com/blogs/graphicdetail/2016/05/daily-chart-16) from *The Economist* (the one on the left). The chart plots the number of billionaires in Russia on the left y-axis and the number of billionaires in rest of the world on the right.

1. Create the chart for Russian billionaires (`p1`).
2. Create the chart for the others (`p2`).
3. Combine `p1` and `p2` into a dual y-axis chart using the code by [Kohske](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2).

Data: (content of `billionaire.csv`)

```
,Russia,World
1996,0,423
1997,4,220
1998,1,221
1999,0,298
2000,0,322
2001,8,530
2002,6,466
2003,17,459
2004,25,562
2005,27,664
2006,33,760
2007,53,893
2008,87,1038
2009,32,761
2010,62,949
2011,101,1109
2012,96,1130
2013,110,1317
2014,111,1535
2015,88,1738
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(extrafont) # for Officiana font
dat <- read.csv("billionaire.csv")
rus <- dat[,1:2]
world <- dat[,-2]

grid.newpage()
p1 <- ggplot(rus, aes(X, Russia)) + geom_line(colour = "#68382C", size = 1.5) + ggtitle("Number in Russia") +
  ylim(0, 200) + labs(x="",y="") +
  theme(#plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,0,0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    text=element_text(family="ITCOfficinaSans LT Book"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#68382C", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.17, vjust=2.12, colour="#68382C", size = 14, family = "ITCOfficinaSans LT Bold")) 

p2 <- ggplot(world, aes(X, World)) + geom_line(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 1.5) +  #ggtitle("Rest of world") +
  ylim(0, 2000) + labs(x="",y="") +
  theme(#plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,0,0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family="ITCOfficinaSans LT Book"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#00a4e6", size=14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=14),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.2, vjust=2.12, colour="#00a4e6", size = 14, family = "ITCOfficinaSans LT Bold"))

# Combining p1 and p2
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, 
                             pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
ax <- ga$children[[2]]
ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)


g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
ggsave("plot.pdf",g, width=5, height=5)
```

To format the texts "Number in Russia" and "Rest of the world" with my chosen font and color, I put them in `ggtitle`. But after combining the charts together in step 3 the title of `p2` is missing, so this is all I got

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is
1. Add the text "Rest of world" in a color and font family of my choice (not the default Helvetica.)
2. Add the label 1996 on the x-axis.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Data set and full code added.
EDIT2: Just FYI, I got all the Officiana fonts from here: http://people.oregonstate.edu/~hanshumw/Specie%20I.D./Signage%20Backup/FONT%20Officina%20full/
EDIT3: Ok I finally how to make it work by fiddling with the plot at the grid level

```
g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.526$label <- c("Number in Russia", "Rest of World")
g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.526$gp$col <- c("#68382C","#00a4e6")
g$grobs[[8]]$children$GRID.text.526$x <- unit(c(-0.175, 0.774), "npc")
```

Put this chunk before `ggsave(...)`, and here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Removing the # from  "+  #ggtitle("Rest of world")" might help.

Comment: Note that in the `ggthemes` packages, there is a `theme_economist()`. This may not help with your question, but might come in handy to save some typing.

Comment: @coffeinjunky Is that like `theme_excel` ?

Comment: @RHA: I tried that already and nothing happened, that's why I commented that out.

Comment: Could you provide the data to make it reproducible? It seems we're missing objects `rus` and `world`

Comment: @Hack-R: Hi, I've added the data. Thanks!

Comment: Please include all data and code necessary to reproduce the plot in your post, so the data (not as a link) and also Kohske's code. I don't think he will mind (as long as Hadley won't see it)

Comment: sharing the data == output of `dput(rus)` & `dput(world)` OR the steps to fully reproduce them from the ZIP file you provided.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Added, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it can be done with `gplot2` with some help from `grid` and `gtable`. I don't try to position the axis labels in the ggplots; rather the axis labels are drawn in their own grob, and then positioned into the gtable.

This draws on code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754891/ggplot2-adding-secondary-y-axis-on-top-of-a-plot/36759348#36759348), which in turn draws on code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989001/how-can-i-put-a-transformed-scale-on-the-right-side-of-a-ggplot2/19082285#19082285) and from the [cowplot](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/switch_axis.R) package). (It requires a little more work to get nicely positioned tick marks and tick labels in the overlay plot drawn with `ggplot2` version 2.1.0. Notice, for instance, they are left justified as in the original *The Economist* rendering.)

```
# Data
dat = read.csv(text = ",Russia,World
1996,0,423
1997,4,220
1998,1,221
1999,0,298
2000,0,322
2001,8,530
2002,6,466
2003,17,459
2004,25,562
2005,27,664
2006,33,760
2007,53,893
2008,87,1038
2009,32,761
2010,62,949
2011,101,1109
2012,96,1130
2013,110,1317
2014,111,1535
2015,88,1738", header  = TRUE)

rus <- dat[,1:2]
world <- dat[,-2]

# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

# The ggplots
p1 <- ggplot(rus, aes(X, Russia)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#68382C", size = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = c(1996, seq(2000, 2015, 5))) +
  scale_y_continuous("", lim = c(0, 200), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#68382C", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(40, 20, 80, 20), "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(world, aes(X, World)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 1.5) +  
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks= c(1996, seq(2000, 2015, 5))) +
  scale_y_continuous("", lim = c(0, 2000), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))

# Get the plot grobs
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Get the location of the plot panel in g1
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))

# Overlap panel for second plot on that of the first plot
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

# ggplot contains many labels that are themselves complex grob; 
# usually a text grob surrounded by margins.
# When moving the grobs from, say, the left to the right of a plot,
# make sure the margins and the justifications are swapped around.
# The function below does the swapping.
# Taken from the cowplot package:
# https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/switch_axis.R 
hinvert_title_grob <- function(grob){

  # Swap the widths
  widths <- grob$widths
  grob$widths[1] <- widths[3]
  grob$widths[3] <- widths[1]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[1] <- widths[3]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[3] <- widths[1]

  # Fix the justification
  grob$children[[1]]$hjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$hjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$vjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$vjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$x <- unit(1, "npc") - grob$children[[1]]$x
  grob
}

# Get the y axis from g2 (axis line, tick marks, and tick mark labels)
index <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")  # Which grob
yaxis <- g2$grobs[[index]]                  # Extract the grob

# yaxis is a complex of grobs containing the axis line, the tick marks, and the tick mark labels.
# The relevant grobs are contained in axis$children:
#   axis$children[[1]] contains the axis line;
#   axis$children[[2]] contains the tick marks and tick mark labels.

# Second, swap tick marks and tick mark labels
ticks <- yaxis$children[[2]]
ticks$widths <- rev(ticks$widths)
ticks$grobs <- rev(ticks$grobs)

# Third, move the tick marks
# Tick mark lengths can change. 
# A function to get the original tick mark length
# Taken from the cowplot package:
# https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/switch_axis.R 
plot_theme <- function(p) {
  plyr::defaults(p$theme, theme_get())
}

tml <- plot_theme(p1)$axis.ticks.length   # Tick mark length
ticks$grobs[[1]]$x <- ticks$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + tml

# Fourth, swap margins and fix justifications for the tick mark labels
ticks$grobs[[2]] <- hinvert_title_grob(ticks$grobs[[2]])

# Fifth, put ticks back into yaxis
yaxis$children[[2]] <- ticks

# Put the transformed yaxis on the right side of g1
g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, g2$widths[g2$layout[index, ]$l], pp$r)
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, yaxis, pp$t, pp$r + 1, pp$b, pp$r + 1, clip = "off", name = "axis-r")

# Labels grob
left = textGrob("Number in Russia", x = 0, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 14, col =  "#68382C"))
right =  textGrob("Rest of World", x = 1, y = 1, just = c("right", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 14, col =  "#00a4e6"))
labs = gTree("Labs", children = gList(left, right))

# New row in the gtable for labels - immediately above the panel
pos = g1$layout[grepl("panel", g1$layout$name), c('t', 'l')]
height = unit(3, "grobheight", left)
g1 <- gtable_add_rows(g1, height, pos$t-1)  

# Put the label in the new row
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, labs, t = pos$t-1, l = pos$l-1, r = pos$l+1)

# Remove a column y label
g1 = g1[, -2]

# Grey rectangle
rect = rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = "grey90"))

# Put the grey rectangles into the margin columns and rows
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, list(rect, rect), t = 1, b = length(g1$heights), l = c(1, length(g1$widths)))
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, list(rect, rect), t = c(1, length(g1$heights)), l = 1, r = length(g1$widths))

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I was looking for. Since you are so familiar  with `grid` and `gtable`, do you know how to overlay `g` on top of a grey background like this: http://i.imgur.com/OmPandU.png?

Comment: Possibly a few ways. Here, I've added margins to p1, then added grey rectangles to the margin rows and columns. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent! I learned a few tricks with `gtable` today, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using R base graphics, rather than ggplot. I didn't change the font family, as that's only portable across systems with the same fonts installed (I don't have Officiana here). It's easy to add a `family` argument to `mtext` to do so.

```
par(mar = c(3, 3, 3, 3), las = 1)
plot(tmp[,c(1,3)], type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ylim = c(0, 2000))
abline(h = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000), col = "grey")
points(tmp[,c(1,3)], type = 'l', col = "blue", lwd = 2)
points(x = tmp[,1], y = tmp[,2] * 10, type = 'l', col = "brown", lwd = 2)
axis(side = 4, at = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000), tick = FALSE,
     col.axis = "blue", line = 1, hadj = 1)
axis(side = 2, at = c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000), tick = FALSE,
     col.axis = "brown", hadj = 1,
     labels = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200))
axis(side = 1, at = c(1996, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015), lwd = 0, line = -1,
     lwd.ticks = 2, col.ticks = "grey")
mtext("Number in Russia", side = 2, col = "brown", at = 2150, line = 2.5,
      adj = 0)
mtext("Rest of World", side = 4, col = "blue", at = 2150, line = 2,
      adj = 1)
```

[image: Plot output]

Answer (score 1):

Your code for combining the plots isn't working in my R session, so I can't help you there. But here are the two questions you asked for:

. use `ggtitle` 
2. use `scale_x_continuous` 
3. Note: I've also changed your `ylim` to `lims` and your `labs` to `theme(..., axis.title= element_blank(), ...)`

```
p1 <- ggplot(rus, aes(X, Russia)) + geom_line(colour = "#68382C", size = 1.5) + ggtitle("Number in Russia") +
  lims(y= c(0, 200)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(1996, seq(2000,2015,5))) +
  theme(#plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,0,0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    text=element_text(family="ITCOfficinaSans LT Book"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#68382C", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title= element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0,vjust=2.12, colour="#68382C", size = 14, family = "ITCOfficinaSans LT Bold")) 

p2 <- ggplot(world, aes(X, World)) + geom_line(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 1.5) + ggtitle("Rest of World") +
  lims(y= c(0, 2000)) +  scale_x_continuous(breaks= c(1996, seq(2000,2015,5))) +
  theme(#plot.margin = unit(c(2,1,0,0), "cm"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    text = element_text(family="ITCOfficinaSans LT Book"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="#00a4e6", size=14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=14),
    axis.title= element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, vjust=2.12, colour="#00a4e6", size = 14, family = "ITCOfficinaSans LT Bold"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `scale_x_continuous`!

Answer (score 1):

This plot can be created by only using ggplot2 as follows: https://rpubs.com/chidungkt/564046

[image]

[image]