# Creating an R line chart in Power BI

Tags: r, powerbi

A good example of what I'm wanting to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347115/reproduce-a-the-economist-chart-with-dual-axis/37369764) except I want to use my own data instead of the data in that post.

Here is the R script seen on that post. I'm thinking all I need to do is change the # Data section to something, but I'm not sure what to replace it with.

Can someone explain how/where I can replace the lines in this R visual with data from two of my own measures in Power BI and replace the X and Y axes with my own Power BI column values?

```
# Data
dat = read.csv(text = ",Russia,World
1996,0,423
1997,4,220
1998,1,221
1999,0,298
2000,0,322
2001,8,530
2002,6,466
2003,17,459
2004,25,562
2005,27,664
2006,33,760
2007,53,893
2008,87,1038
2009,32,761
2010,62,949
2011,101,1109
2012,96,1130
2013,110,1317
2014,111,1535
2015,88,1738", header  = TRUE)

rus <- dat[,1:2]
world <- dat[,-2]

# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

# The ggplots
p1 <- ggplot(rus, aes(X, Russia)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#68382C", size = 1.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = c(1996, seq(2000, 2015, 5))) +
  scale_y_continuous("", lim = c(0, 200), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "gray50", size = 0.5),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#68382C", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(40, 20, 80, 20), "pt"))

p2 <- ggplot(world, aes(X, World)) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 1.5) +  
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks= c(1996, seq(2000, 2015, 5))) +
  scale_y_continuous("", lim = c(0, 2000), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "#00a4e6", size = 14),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))

# Get the plot grobs
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# Get the location of the plot panel in g1
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))

# Overlap panel for second plot on that of the first plot
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

# ggplot contains many labels that are themselves complex grob; 
# usually a text grob surrounded by margins.
# When moving the grobs from, say, the left to the right of a plot,
# make sure the margins and the justifications are swapped around.
# The function below does the swapping.
# Taken from the cowplot package:
# https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/switch_axis.R 
hinvert_title_grob <- function(grob){

  # Swap the widths
  widths <- grob$widths
  grob$widths[1] <- widths[3]
  grob$widths[3] <- widths[1]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[1] <- widths[3]
  grob$vp[[1]]$layout$widths[3] <- widths[1]

  # Fix the justification
  grob$children[[1]]$hjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$hjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$vjust <- 1 - grob$children[[1]]$vjust 
  grob$children[[1]]$x <- unit(1, "npc") - grob$children[[1]]$x
  grob
}

# Get the y axis from g2 (axis line, tick marks, and tick mark labels)
index <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")  # Which grob
yaxis <- g2$grobs[[index]]                  # Extract the grob

# yaxis is a complex of grobs containing the axis line, the tick marks, and the tick mark labels.
# The relevant grobs are contained in axis$children:
#   axis$children[[1]] contains the axis line;
#   axis$children[[2]] contains the tick marks and tick mark labels.

# Second, swap tick marks and tick mark labels
ticks <- yaxis$children[[2]]
ticks$widths <- rev(ticks$widths)
ticks$grobs <- rev(ticks$grobs)

# Third, move the tick marks
# Tick mark lengths can change. 
# A function to get the original tick mark length
# Taken from the cowplot package:
# https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/blob/master/R/switch_axis.R 
plot_theme <- function(p) {
  plyr::defaults(p$theme, theme_get())
}

tml <- plot_theme(p1)$axis.ticks.length   # Tick mark length
ticks$grobs[[1]]$x <- ticks$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + tml

# Fourth, swap margins and fix justifications for the tick mark labels
ticks$grobs[[2]] <- hinvert_title_grob(ticks$grobs[[2]])

# Fifth, put ticks back into yaxis
yaxis$children[[2]] <- ticks

# Put the transformed yaxis on the right side of g1
g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, g2$widths[g2$layout[index, ]$l], pp$r)
g1 <- gtable_add_grob(g1, yaxis, pp$t, pp$r + 1, pp$b, pp$r + 1, clip = "off", name = "axis-r")

# Labels grob
left = textGrob("Number in Russia", x = 0, y = 1, just = c("left", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 14, col =  "#68382C"))
right =  textGrob("Rest of World", x = 1, y = 1, just = c("right", "top"), gp = gpar(fontsize = 14, col =  "#00a4e6"))
labs = gTree("Labs", children = gList(left, right))

# New row in the gtable for labels - immediately above the panel
pos = g1$layout[grepl("panel", g1$layout$name), c('t', 'l')]
height = unit(3, "grobheight", left)
g1 <- gtable_add_rows(g1, height, pos$t-1)  

# Put the label in the new row
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, labs, t = pos$t-1, l = pos$l-1, r = pos$l+1)

# Remove a column y label
g1 = g1[, -2]

# Grey rectangle
rect = rectGrob(gp = gpar(col = NA, fill = "grey90"))

# Put the grey rectangles into the margin columns and rows
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, list(rect, rect), t = 1, b = length(g1$heights), l = c(1, length(g1$widths)))
g1 = gtable_add_grob(g1, list(rect, rect), t = c(1, length(g1$heights)), l = 1, r = length(g1$widths))

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

For reference purposes, the Power BI measures I am using are called:

Day - which is just a calculated column of "days" 1-5000

Value1-  which is just a measure designed to calculate the sum of values per day

Value2  -  which is just a measure designed to calculater the sum of values per day

I'm trying to show Value1 on one line and Value2 on the other

Comment: How can a measure be a list of numbers? A measure aggregates numbers.

Comment: Lol it can be a list when it's broken up by date/some other dimension.... but I guess technically you are correct... that's my bad

corrected ;)

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly (and I'm not sure I do) but I think this is a simple case of replacing the values in the code with the values in your power BI dataset. So, when you populate the R Visual with the values from your Power BI Table, the simplest approach would be do re-assign the value in the code with your values.

Maybe upload a screen shot of your Power BI visuals page. Also a note the distinction between line chart and  scatter chart.