# axis.line.x.top give no change when i use ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use theme call to change the size of axis lines, the problem is that four axis cannot be changed simultaneously, and upper x axis can't be changed. So, I use the axis.line.x.top to change the upper x axis, but no change in plot. who can help me save this problems. Thank you.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you actually have an axis on the top of your plot? This would be fairly uncommon, but otherwise there's nothing for `axis.line.x.top` to work on

Comment: Dear Chen, could you post your code and data.as it is difficult to help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 - adding secondary y-axis on top of a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754891/ggplot2-adding-secondary-y-axis-on-top-of-a-plot)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sec.axis` argument in `scale.x.continuous`. Secondary axis will inherit proporerties from the primary axis. Please see below an example:

```
data(mpg)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(size = 2, colour = "red", linetype = "dotted")) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "cty, miles per gallon", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . * 0.42, name = "cty, kilometers per liter"))
```

Output:
[image: ggplot2]