# Dual axis chart with ggplot solution stopped to work

Tags: r, ggplot2

until now was a nice solution to plot charts with dual axes using ggplot like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(ggthemes)

# extract gtable
ggplot_second_axis <- function(p1, p2){
  p2 <- p2 + theme() %+replace% 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))

  grid.newpage()
  g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
  g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

  # overlap the panel of 2nd plot on that of 1st plot
  pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "panel", se = t:r))
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "panel")]], pp$t, pp$l, pp$b, pp$l)

  # axis tweaks
  ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
  ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
  ax <- ga$children[[2]]
  ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
  ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
  ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
  g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)

  ia2 <- which(g2$layout$name == "ylab")
  ga2 <- g2$grobs[[ia2]]
  ga2$rot <- 90
  g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia2, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
  g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ga2, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)

  return(g)
}

# two plots
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_line(colour = "blue") 
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, drat)) + geom_line(colour = "red") 
f <- ggplot_second_axis(p1,p2)
grid.draw(f)
```

Everything seemed to work OK until now, but recently I get the following error:

```
Error in g2$grobs[[ia2]]: attempt to select less than one element in get1index.
Changes in system: merged dplyr and data.table into dtplyr. Updated R to 3.3.2 from 3.3.1
```

Downgrade doesn't work.

Comment: Consider downgrading package versions to last working setup.

Comment: Roman, is it too much to ask you to check whether you can reproduce the error?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot/40746716#40746716) may be useful.

Comment: Also [the other answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336658/4341440) has been updated to work with the newest `ggplot2`.

Comment: Works for me. ggplot2 version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

ia2 <- which(g2$layout$name == "ylab")

to:

ia2 <- which(g2$layout$name == "ylab-l")

(...that worked for me with the latest ggplot update)