# ggplot2 add separate legend each for two Y axes in facet plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add legends next to axis titles. I followed [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746716/1691723) to get the plot.

**How to add legend on two y axes?**. I would like to have legend on both left and right Y-axes. In the plot below, the right y-axis lacks legend symbols.

**Also is it possible to give unique color for text similar to symbols in legend.**

**At the same time, how to rotate legend key symbols to vertical position?**

The code I have so far:

```
## install ggplot2 as follows:
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")

packageVersion('ggplot2')
# [1] ‘2.2.0.9000’

packageVersion('data.table')
# [1] ‘1.9.7’

# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# data
df1 <- structure(list(plate_num = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L,
                                    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), 
                      `Before Treatment` = c(662.253098499674, 684.416067929458, 688.284595300261, 
                                             692.532637075718, 728.988910632746, 684.708496732026, 
                                             703.390706806283, 673.920966688439, 644.945573770492, 504.423076923077, 
                                             580.263743455497, 580.563767168084, 689.6014445174, 804.740789473684, 
                                             815.792020928712, 789.234139960759, 778.087753765553, 745.777922926192, 
                                             787.762434554974, 780.828758169935, 781.265839320705, 732.683552631579, 
                                             773.964052287582, 713.941253263708, 724.459070072037, 838.899148657498),
                      `After Treatment` = c(440.251141552511, 431.039190071848, 460.349216710183, 479.798955613577, 
                                            441.123939986954, 436.17908496732, 453.938481675393, 437.237753102547,
                                            448.52, 426.70925684485, 390.417539267016, 359.66121648136, 451.969796454366, 
                                            515.611842105263, 542.325703073904, 547.637671680837, 518.316306483301, 478.536903984324, 
                                            501.122382198953, 494.475816993464, 474.581319399086, 438.515789473684, 
                                            440.251633986928, 407.945822454308, 413.571054354944, 537.290111329404),
                      Ratio = c(1.50426208132996, 1.58782793698034, 1.49513580194398, 1.443380876455, 1.6525716347526, 
                                1.56978754903694, 1.54952870311901, 1.54131467812749, 1.43794161636157, 1.18212358609901, 1.48626453756382, 
                                                 1.61419619509676, 1.5257688675819, 1.5607492376201, 1.50424738548219, 
                                                 1.44116115594897, 1.50118324280547, 1.55845435684647, 1.57199610821259, 
                                                 1.57910403569899, 1.64622122149676, 1.67082593197148, 1.75800381540563, 
                                                 1.75008840381905, 1.75171608951693, 1.56135229547), 
                      grp = c("wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X",
                              "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "wt-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", 
                              "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X", "mu-3X")),
                 .Names = c("plate_num", "Before Treatment", "After Treatment", "Ratio", "grp"),
                 row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")


max1 <- max(c(df1$`Before Treatment`, df1$`After Treatment`))
max2 <- max(df1$Ratio)
df1$norm_ratio <- df1$Ratio / (max2/max1)
df1 <- melt(df1, id = c("plate_num", 'grp'))
df1$plate_num <- factor(df1$plate_num, levels = 1:13, ordered = TRUE)

# plot
p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_num, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment', 'After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment', 'After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 2, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'blue'), guide = 'legend') + 
  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = variable), col = 'red', size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = variable), col = 'red', size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~ grp) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (max2 / max1),
                                         name = 'Ratio of Main Effect of Before and After Treatment\n')) +

  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, face="bold", angle = 0, vjust = 1), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold", color = 'black'),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(size=15, face="bold", color = 'red'),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(size=15, face="bold", color = 'red'),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold"),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.position = c(-0.28, 0.4),
        legend.direction = 'vertical',
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15, angle = 90),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = NA, fill = NA),
        legend.key.width=unit(2,"line"),
        legend.key.height=unit(2,"line"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=15, face="bold", color = "black", angle = 0),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,4,1,3), "cm")) +
  ylab('Main Effect of TDP43\n\n\n') + 
  xlab('\nPlate Number')

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain your 3rd question? I don't see what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please look at the legend on left y axis: The legend keys are supposed to be in vertical orientation, but they are aligned horizontally.

Comment: In the code, I used `legend.direction = 'vertical'`, but still no effect

Comment: Thanks. The code refers to an object called `variable`. I believe it's missing from the question.

Comment: variable name comes from `melt.data.table`. It is an automatic name assigned by `melt` function

Comment: I could have given user defined name by using `variable.name` argument in the `melt` function

Comment: In my code, I mentioned libraries used in this task. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*In order to make this a bit shorter I cut down your `theme` definitions.*

---

I make use of the fact that you can extract single grobs from your ggplot elements. In this case we extract 3 legends.

For the desired result we need to create 4 plots:

1. Plot *p*:  a plot without legends
2. Plot *l1*: a plot for the green legend
3. Plot *l2*: a plot for the blue legend
4. Plot *l3*: a plot for the red legend

We make use of the function `get_legend()` which is part of the package `cowplot`. It lets you extract the legend of a plot.

After we extracted both legends for the left side we use `arrangeGrob` to combine them and name that combined legend `llegend`.
After we extracted the red legend, we us `grid.arrange` to plot all three objects (`llegend`, `p` and `rlegend`).

Concerning the orientation of the legend keys you should notice that we print the legends on top of the corresponding plots. That way we can use `editGrob` to rotate the (combined) legends after extracting them and the legend keys have the correct orientation.

This is all the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)

# actual plot without legends
p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_num, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment', 'After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 1, show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment', 'After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 2, show.legend = F) +

  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = 'Test'), col = 'red', size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = 'Test'), col = 'red', size = 2) +
  facet_wrap(~ grp) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ . * (max2 / max1),
                                         name = 'Ratio of Main Effect of Before and After Treatment\n')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('green', 'blue'), guide = 'legend') +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=11, face="bold", angle = 0, vjust = 1), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=11, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11, face="bold", color = 'black'),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(size=11, face="bold", color = 'red'),
        axis.title.y.right = element_text(size=11, face="bold", color = 'red', margin=margin(0,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=11, face="bold", margin=margin(0,-30,0,0)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size=15, face="bold", color = "black", angle = 0),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm")) +
  ylab('Main Effect of TDP43\n\n\n') + 
  xlab('\nPlate Number')

# Create legend on the left 
l1 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_num, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('Before Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 2, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = 'green', guide = 'legend') +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
        legend.text = element_text(angle = 0, colour = c('green', 'blue')),
        legend.position = 'top',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, 'cm'),
        legend.box.margin = unit(c(0, 0 , -2.5 ,0), 'cm'))

l2 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_num, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 1, show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('After Treatment')), aes(color = variable), size = 2, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = 'blue', guide = 'legend') +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
        legend.text = element_text(angle = 0, colour = c('blue')),
        legend.position = 'top',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, 'cm'),
        legend.box.margin = unit(c(0, 0 , -2.5 ,0), 'cm'))

legend1 <- get_legend(l1)
legend2 <- get_legend(l2)

# Combine green and blue legend
llegend <- editGrob(arrangeGrob(grobs = list(legend1, legend2), 
                       nrow = 1, ncol = 2), vp = viewport(angle = 90))

# Plot with legend on the right
l3 <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = plate_num, y = value, group = variable)) +
   geom_line(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = variable), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df1, variable %in% c('norm_ratio')), aes(color = variable), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = 'red', guide = 'legend') +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
        legend.text = element_text(angle = 0, colour = 'red'),
        legend.position = 'top',
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0, 'cm'),
        legend.box.margin = unit(c(0, 0, -3, 0), 'cm'))

# extract legend
rlegend <- editGrob(get_legend(l3), vp = viewport(angle = 270))

grid.arrange(grobs = list(llegend, p, rlegend), ncol = 3, 
             widths = unit(c(3, 16, 3), "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. I made it a bit shorter. For the legend plots you dont need facets etc. since we are only interested in the legends. Also removed the code for your data.

Comment: I think this is only possible for the overall legend. So if you want green and blue text for the legend on the left you would need to split the legend up. So you would have 3 legends. Then you need to arrange legend 1 and legend 2 and afterwards arrange the overall objects. You get me?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: for `l1`, setting `legend.margin = margin(0, 2, 0, 0, 'cm')` and for `l2` ,setting `legend.margin = margin(0, -2, 0, 0, 'cm')`
removes overlapping legend texts in `llegend`. Could you please update the answer if it also works for you. Thanks

Comment: I guess yours overlapped because your text siz is bigger in the original.

Comment: Also note cowplot::get_legend

Comment: @Axeman ah nice. Did not know its implemented somewhere. Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I worked on a very similar answer yesterday, but couldn't get the legends to rotate ;). Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

This source has an simple and easy answer. It describes the logic used by ggplot to create a legend based on assigned aes mapping, then provides a step by step solution without all this extra code. Perfect for ggplot with a second y axis, that is, plots that combine multiple geom_ or stat_summary objects into one beautifully slick graph :)

http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/#manually-adding-legend-items-guides-override.aes