# How to draw rainfall runoff graph in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a hydrologist, the Rainfall Hyetograph and Streamflow Hydrograph is commonly used. It looks like the figure below. 
[image: Hyteograph and Hydrograph]

The X-axis represents Date and left Y-axis which is reversed represents rainfall and right Y-axis represents discharge.

I have a rainfall table and a discharge table.

```
  ####Rain Table####                   ####Discharge Table####
   Date         Value                     Date         Value
2000-01-01       13.2                   2000-01-01      150
2000-01-02       9.5                    2000-01-01      135
2000-01-03       7.3                    2000-01-01      58
2000-01-04       0.2                    2000-01-01      38
```

Here is my code.

```
  ggplot(rain,aes(x=DATE,y=value)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
    scale_y_reverse()+
    geom_line(data =discharge,aes(x=DATE,y=value))
```

But I don't know how to represent these value in two different Y-axis.

Comment: ggplot2 does not like dual axes. A web search will find examples of how to achieve them, but the code is rarely pretty. It might be better to use something like rCharts and a javascript library for the chart, if it's really what you want to achieve.

Comment: Further to first comment: there is some support for dual axes in the latest ggplot2; an example here https://rpubs.com/MarkusLoew/226759

Comment: Even with `sec_axis()`, ggplot2 makes you do manual 1:1 transformation work to get the second axis scaled properly. I grok this is a seminal chart in this particular branch of science, but you might want to consider base graphics or overlaying plots instead in the long run.

Comment: Did you really mean to replicate `2000-01-01` for the discharge values?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot/40746716#40746716)

Answer (score 6):

It's possible in ggplot using the sec_axis() function to display a second axis that is a transformation of the first. Since precipitation can be transformed to a volume using watershed area (or discharge transformed into a depth), it's possible to use sec_axis to make a hyetograph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

df <- read_csv("date, precip_in, discharge_cfs
                2000-01-01, 13.2, 150
                2000-01-02, 9.5, 135
                2000-01-03, 7.3, 58
                2000-01-04, 0.2, 38")

watershedArea_sqft <- 100

# Convert the precipitation to the same units as discharge. These steps will based on your units
df$precip_ft <- df$precip_in/12
df$precip_cuft <- df$precip_ft * watershedArea_sqft

# Calculate the range needed to avoid having your hyetograph and hydrograph overlap 
maxRange <- 1.1*(max(df$precip_cuft) + max(df$discharge_cfs))

# Create a function to backtransform the axis labels for precipitation
precip_labels <- function(x) {(x / watershedArea_sqft) * 12}

# Plot the data
ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = date)) +
  # Use geom_tile to create the inverted hyetograph. geom_tile has a bug that displays a warning message for height and width, you can ignore it.
  geom_tile(aes(y = -1*(precip_cuft/2-maxRange), # y = the center point of each bar
                height = precip_cuft,
                width = 1),
            fill = "gray50",
            color = "white") +
  # Plot your discharge data
  geom_line(aes(y = discharge_cfs),
            color = "blue") +
  # Create a second axis with sec_axis() and format the labels to display the original precipitation units.
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Discharge (cfs)",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~-1*(.-maxRange),
                                         name = "Precipitation (in)",
                                         labels = precip_labels))
```

[image: Example hyeto-hydrograph]

Answer (score 5):

I think the comments make a strong case for not using `ggplot2` for this problem: it will not be elegant or straightforward. So here is an answer that uses the `highcharter` package instead.

I've used the data provided as an example, except that discharge dates were altered to be the same as rain dates.

[Here is the interactive result](http://rpubs.com/neilfws/247586) published as HTML.

Here's a screenshot. [image]
I would echo the comment above: although this may be a standard in hydrology, reversed dual axes are very misleading. I think you could achieve something more informative and attractive using `ggplot2` with some experimentation.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

rainfall <- data.frame(date = as.Date(rep(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04"), 2), "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                       value = c(13.2, 9.5, 7.3, 0.2, 150, 135, 58, 38), 
                       variable = c(rep("rain", 4), rep("discharge", 4)))

hc <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(list(title = list(text = "rainfall depth (mm)"), reversed = TRUE), 
                     list(title = list(text = "flow (m3/s)"), 
                      opposite = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = filter(rainfall, variable == "rain") %>% mutate(value = -value) %>% .$value, type = "column") %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = filter(rainfall, variable == "discharge") %>% .$value, type = "spline", yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = dataset$rain.date, title = list(text = "date"))

hc
```

Answer (score 3):

Using base R:

```
## Make data
dates <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"),
              to=as.Date("2015-01-10"), by="days")
flow <- c(0,0,1,3,7,11,8,6,4,5)
rain <- c(0,1,2,5,4,0,0,0,1,0)

## Plot rainfall first
par(xaxs="i", yaxs="i", mar=c(5,5,5,5))
plot(dates, rain, type="h", ylim=c(max(rain)*1.5,0),
 axes=FALSE, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, col="blue",
 lwd=50, lend="square")
axis(4)
mtext("Rainfall", side=4, line=3)

## Plot flow on top
par(new=TRUE)
plot(dates, flow, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(0, max(flow)*1.2))
```

[base R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cQsM.jpg)

Using plotly:

```
## Plotly
library(plotly)
rainAx <- list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = "Rain",
  ##autorange="reversed",
  range = c(max(rain)*1.5,0),
  showgrid=FALSE
    )

plot_ly() %>%
add_trace(
    x=~dates, y=~flow,
    type="scatter", mode="lines") %>%
add_trace(
    x=~dates, y=~rain,
    type="bar", yaxis="y2") %>%
layout(yaxis2=rainAx)
```

[plotly plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di6Ky.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I like the post by jpshanno a lot and will use it since it is flexible and fits to other code I have going. Here is a packaged solution I just found:

```
library(EcoHydRology)
dataforhydrograph <- as.data.frame(cbind(date = 1:20, precipitation = runif(20,0,100),discharge  = runif(20,0,100)))
dataforhydrograph$date <- as.Date(dataforhydrograph$date, format = c("%Y-%m-%d"), origin = "1998-01-01")
hydrograph(input=dataforhydrograph)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this R code using "plotly" library you can display rainfall-runoff plots.

```
library(plotly)  
rainAx = list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  title = "Rainfall (mm)",
  #autorange="reversed",
  range = c(300,0),
  showgrid=FALSE
)

date = hidromet.dia$date.daily #dates at daily format, however you can use any temporal resolution
flow = hidromet.dia$flow.daily # flow data
rainfall = hidromet.dia$rainfall.daily # rainfall data

plot_ly() %>%
add_trace(
  x=~date, y=~flow,
  type="scatter", mode="lines", line = list
  (color = 'black', width = 1, 
  dash = 'solid'),name ='Streamflow') %>%
add_trace(
 x=~date, y=~rainfall,
 type="bar", yaxis="y2", marker = list
 (color ="blue",width = 1),name = 'rainfall') %>%
 layout(title = "Rainfall-Streamflow",xaxis =list
 (title = "time (daily)"), yaxis=list
 (title="Q  m³/s",range=c(0,1300)),yaxis2=rainAx)
```

Comment: Where does your `hidromet.dia` come from?

Comment: "hidromet.dia" would be your daily hidrometeorological data (dataframe). This code is an adaptation from @joelnNC answer.