# plot with x axis at the bottom and y axis on top in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with coordinate data that looks like this,

```
V1       V2      V3       V4    
10253363 10273825 9982154 10003803     
10265080 10285697 9993266 10015040     
10250800 10271301 9979709 10001394     
10254775 10275140 9983264 10004815     
10268607 10288871 9995004 10016450     
10263978 10284276 9992831 10014300
```

And I'd like to generate a plot similar to the one shown below, 
[image]

I tried this,

```
blast <- fread("../plots/coords.tsv")
blast$id = as.numeric(rownames(blast))
ggplot(blast)+ 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=V1,xmax=V2,ymin=V3,ymax=V4, group = id), alpha=0.2) + 
  scale_y_continuous(position = "top")
```

and ended up with the plot below instead.

[image]
It seems like y axis position could only be flipped between right and left. Therefore, this isn't working for me.

How do I generate the intended plot in `ggplot2`? Or is there another way to get at that?

Comment: Is that a Sankey graph?

Answer (score 0):

That's not so easy, as you need to reshape and then trick ggplot2 a little.

The conversion factor is needed, since `ggplot` doesn't really allow separate axes, only relabeling based on simple conversions.

Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot/40746716#40746716).

You have a bunch of overlapping ranges, so it doesn't quite look like your example plot.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

conversion_factor <- mean(c(blast$V3, blast$V4)) / mean(c(blast$V1, blast$V2))
blast2 <- mutate(blast, V3 = V3 / conversion_factor, V4 = V4 / conversion_factor)

blast_long <- blast2 %>% 
  gather(var, x, -id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(y = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
         order = c(1, 2, 4, 3)) %>% 
  arrange(order)

ggplot(blast_long, aes(x, y, group = id))+ 
  geom_polygon(alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * conversion_factor))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, Axeman. I guess my post didn't come across as I intended. clear. sec_axis only seems to be adding the x axis labels on the top. Ideally what I want is just two axes with the x axis (limits will be based on columns V1 and V2)  at the bottom and the y axis (with limits based on V3, V4) on the top. Then I'd like to have rectangles/segments drawn between these two axes.