# Overlaying histogram with different y-scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm struggling with the following issue:

I want to plot two histograms, but since the statistics of one of the two classes is much less than the other I need to add a second y-axis to allow a direct comparison of the values.

I report below the code I used at the moment and the result.

Thank you in advance!

```
ggplot(data,aes(x= x ,group=class,fill=class)) + geom_histogram(position="identity",
  alpha=0.5, bins = 20)+ theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: [This previous so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot/40746716#40746716) could answer your question.

Comment: Maybe you should be plotting densities instead of counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following situation where you have 800 versus 200 observations:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(1000, rep(c(1, 2), c(800, 200))),
  class = rep(c("A", "B"), c(800, 200))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = class)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, position = "identity", alpha = 0.5,
  # Note that y = stat(count) is the default behaviour
                 mapping = aes(y = stat(count)))
```

[image]

You could scale the counts for each group to a maximum of 1 by using `y = stat(ncount)`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = class)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, position = "identity", alpha = 0.5,
                 mapping = aes(y = stat(ncount)))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set `y = stat(density)` to have the total area integrate to 1.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = class)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, position = "identity", alpha = 0.5,
                 mapping = aes(y = stat(density)))
```

[image]

Note that after ggplot 3.3.0 `stat()` probably will get replaced by `after_stat()`.

Comment: thank you master, that was the solution! Simple and fast, I don't know how I missed it.  You helped me a lot. Have a nice day! =)

Answer (score 0):

How about comparing them side by side with facets?

```
ggplot(data,aes(x= x ,group=class,fill=class)) +
  geom_histogram(position="identity",
                 alpha=0.5,
                 bins = 20) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~class, scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, since I have to repeat the same histogram for 6 sets I'm trying to summarize both the histograms in one chart.
Anyway, if I won't be able to find a way, I'm going to follow your suggestion. Best.