# In ggplot2, how to add another y-axis in the figure?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Here is my data (called "data" and is a CSV format file):

```
attitude,order,min,max,mean,SpRate
Commanding,7,0.023005096,1.6517,0.681777825,5.66572238
Friendly,10,0.20565908,1.7535,0.843770095,6.191950464
Hostile,12,0.105828885,2.4161,1.128603777,6.493506494
Insincere,1,0.110689225,1.5551,0.730545923,5.115089514
Irony,4,0.089307133,2.2395,0.955312553,5.249343832
Joking,2,0.165717303,2.1871,0.94512688,5.141388175
Neutral,5,-0.044620705,1.5322,0.696879247,5.420054201
Polite,11,0.170151929,1.8467,0.873735105,6.191950464
Praising,8,0.192402573,2.0631,0.972857404,5.797101449
Rude,13,0.249746688,2.2885,1.100819511,6.644518272
Serious,6,0.011312206,1.7195,0.693606814,5.649717514
Sincere,9,-0.09135461,1.6409,0.659525513,5.813953488
Suggesting,3,0.072541529,1.8345,0.82999014,5.249343832
```

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot (data, aes(x=order))+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=order-0.1, xmax=order+0.1, ymin = min, ymax=max), size=1, alpha=0,color="black")+
    geom_bar(aes(y=SpRate, fill="SpRate"),stat="identity", alpha=0.2, width=0.9)+
    geom_point(aes(y=min, shape="min"), size=5, fill="white")+ 
    geom_point(aes(y=mean, shape="mean"), size=5)+
    geom_point(aes(y=max, shape="max"), size=5)+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1:13), labels=c("Insincere","Joking","Suggesting","Irony","Neutral","Serious","Commanding","Praising","Sincere","Friendly","Polite","Hostile", "Rude"))+
    xlab("")+ylab("")+theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=25,angle=45, vjust=0.5, color="black"))+
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 20))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20))+
    labs(shape = "f0:", fill = "SpRate:")+
    scale_shape_manual(values=c("min"=15,"max"=16,"mean"=18))+
    scale_fill_manual(values= "black")+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=20))
```

So, as you can see from the plot, there are two plots indeed: A rectanglular with points and a bar-plot, but the y-axis of bar-plot obviously not adapt into the y-axis presented well, so, how to add another y-axis in the right of the whole plot which could adjust for the bar-plot better? (i.e. I want the y-axis of rectangular presented from 0 to 2.5 and bar-plot from 0 to 7)

Comment: Secondary axis are not supported by ggplot2 because its author (rightly) believes they shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the second y-axis in ggplot2.

- Use this example for one panel plot (http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2)
- Use my example for multiple panel plot ([Dual y axis in ggplot2 for multiple panel figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981416/dual-y-axis-in-ggplot2-for-multiple-panel-figure))