# How to add a label to a transformed scale axis on the right hand side of a ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The linked question below worked for me, all except I would like to label the transformed axis on the rhs of the plot.

[How can I put a transformed scale on the right side of a ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989001/how-can-i-put-a-transformed-scale-on-the-right-side-of-a-ggplot2?newreg=7a263addc6c042aebe2d9598a94d7dd9)

The source code provided in the linked question is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

LakeLevels<-data.frame(Day=c(1:365),Elevation=sin(seq(0,2*pi,2*pi/364))*10+100)
p1 <- ggplot(data=LakeLevels) + geom_line(aes(x=Day,y=Elevation)) + 
      scale_y_continuous(name="Elevation (m)",limits=c(75,125))

p2<-ggplot(data=LakeLevels)+geom_line(aes(x=Day, y=Elevation))+
    scale_y_continuous(name="Elevation (ft)", limits=c(75,125),           
    breaks=c(80,90,100,110,120),
             labels=c("262", "295", "328", "361", "394"))

#extract gtable
g1<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

#overlap the panel of the 2nd plot on that of the 1st plot

pp<-c(subset(g1$layout, name=="panel", se=t:r))
g<-gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name=="panel")]], pp$t, pp$l,pp$b, pp$l)



  ia <- which(g2$layout$name == "axis-l")
   ga <- g2$grobs[[ia]]
   ax <- ga$children[[2]]
   ax$widths <- rev(ax$widths)
   ax$grobs <- rev(ax$grobs)
   ax$grobs[[1]]$x <- ax$grobs[[1]]$x - unit(1, "npc") + unit(0.15, "cm")
   g <- gtable_add_cols(g, g2$widths[g2$layout[ia, ]$l], length(g$widths) - 1)
   g <- gtable_add_grob(g, ax, pp$t, length(g$widths) - 1, pp$b)
   # draw it
   grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Did you look at all the answers to the question? It seems like there's at least one that has an axis label on the right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I put a transformed scale on the right side of a ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989001/how-can-i-put-a-transformed-scale-on-the-right-side-of-a-ggplot2)