# R -- Add second y axis to histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've looked in many places, and while I can find posts on things like adding a second histogram to the plot, adding a second y-axis to a plot with two time series, I can't find anything on my problem. I have a histogram created with ggplot2, qplot function. I need to add a second y-axis, to the right side of the plot, and I want the scale to go from 0 to 1.

Here's my code:

```
p <- qplot(subsetted$xvar, geom = "histogram", binwidth = .5, xlim= c(0, 100), main = "Histogram for Item 1")
```

Thanks!

Comment: ggplot2 doesn't support secondary axes.

Comment: This might help you: [how-can-i-put-a-transformed-scale-on-the-right-side-of-a-ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18989001/how-can-i-put-a-transformed-scale-on-the-right-side-of-a-ggplot2)